# Specifying methods when using Responder

Tags: python

I am using the Responder(https://python-responder.org/en/latest/) and I am trying to replace it from Flask.
Is there a way to limit HTTP methods like Flask?

Example (Flask):

```
@ app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def foo ():
     pass
```

Thank you,